# Search path of symlink's source file

Tags: path, symbolic-link, libraries

I have my main script which sources a bash file in the same folder:

```
 $ cd
 $ mkdir mysrc && cd mysrc
 $ echo -e 'MY_LIB_NB=123987' > mylib.sh
 $ echo -e '#!/usr/bin/env bash\nsource mylib.sh\necho "My lib number: $MY_LIB_NB"\necho "I am in $(pwd) and I am running script $(readlink -f $0)"' > myscript.sh
 $ chmod +x myscript.sh
 $ ./myscript.sh
 My lib number: 123987
 I am in /home/me/mysrc and I am running script /home/me/mysrc/myscript.sh
```

So far so good. Now I symlink the script to a bin folder andrun it from there:

```
$ mkdir bin
$ ln -s $HOME/mysrc/myscript.sh $HOME/mysrc/bin/myscript
$ cd bin
$ ./myscript
./myscript: line 2: mylib.sh: No such file or directory
My lib number: 
I am in /home/me/mysrc/bin and I am running script /home/me/mysrc/myscript.sh
```

I would like my original scripts to source files located in their folder. Is there a simple way to do that, without having to explicitly give absolute paths to the library file?

Comment: Symlink your other stuff as well or, as you can see from your output, `cd`to the path of `$0` to change your working directory to the directory where the script resides instead of the symlink location.

Answer (score 1):

This bash script fragment should help

```
# get the path to the currently running script:
self=$0 

# test if $self is a symlink:
if [ -L $self ] ; then 
  # readlink returns the path to the file the link points to:
  target=`readlink $self` 
else
  target=$self
fi

# strip off the script name from the path:
path=`dirname $target` 

# $path/mylib.sh now points to the mylib.sh 
# file in the folder where the original script is:
source $path/mylib.sh
```

http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/readlink.1.html

http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/dirname.1.html

Comment: Thanks I was thinking of doing that in case no original answer would pop up.. SO far I think it's the simplest way of doing it. Ps: your links are dead!

Comment: It's best to prefer simplicity over originality. The former tends to be more reliable. :) I fixed the links. Thanks.